# Where to get the CherryPy auth_digest module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy web site running on a virtual ubuntu linux server.  I'm attempting to move the application to a second, larger-memory server.  Both servers appears to have CherryPy 3.2 installed (I just used apt-get to install it on the newer server).

The newer server, however, does not appear to have the CherryPy auth_digest module installed which is what I'm using for authentication.  It is present in the CherryPy egg on the older server.

How can I update my copy of CherryPy to incorporate that module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up downloading the tar file (which I think may be a minor version or two more recent than what apt-get knows about) and using setup.py to install it.  This version includes the digest authorization module.